# Invalid Characters appearing in .js files

Tags: javascript, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, invalid-characters

I'm hosting a website currently that was working perfectly fine,

but then after trying to test out Chrome DevTools's Lighthouse feature, two of my js files started having Chinese characters show up in them, which the console is calling invalid characters, and my website is now refusing to run.

I've tried to swap out the files several times with older versions, change the encoding between UTF-16, UTF-8 BOM, & UTF-8, and removing any hidden special characters using tools I found online, but nothing seems to be working.

Does anyone know a way I can fix this?

For more information on what could be causing this, I'm using FileZilla to upload them to my VPS, and my website is going through Cloudflare.

Edit: The files also work perfectly fine on my localhost version of the site, its just on the live one that they are having this issue.

Edit 2: Performing another Lighthouse audit on the site, (this time in desktop mode vs mobile), seems to have fixed the problem entirely, though the website is still not working on mobile devices, probably for this same reason now knowing what fixed it. Any help on why this is happening or how I can fix it is still appreciated.

Comment: The console will tell you where the invalid characters are.

Comment: The console says the invalid character is the first of each, but it seems to be more of an encoding issue since the entire files appear corrupted when looking into Sources tab, and one of the files doesn't even have a difference that the original with its first character.